# Matt Gallagher's iOS Tone Generator

Tags: swift, audio, core-audio

Can someone point me to a working version of Matt Gallagher's Tone Generator?

http://www.cocoawithlove.com/assets/objc-era/ToneGenerator.zip

As Matt says, it hasn't been updated and apparently got broken by newer APIs. I updated what I could figure out needed updating and now it compiles and runs with only deprecation warnings but all it does is make clicking sounds when the "Play" and "Stop" button are touched. I've gone through the code and looked at the documentation in Xcode for the API but it's a steep learning curve. I would love to have a working version so I could tinker with it to learn more. Has anyone updated it? Or a similar tone generator?

I tried using the ToneOutputUnit class from hotpaw2 by calling it as follows.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let unit = ToneOutputUnit()
        unit.toneCount = 64000
        unit.setFrequency(1000.0)
        unit.setToneVolume(0.5)
        unit.startToneForDuration(2.0)
        unit.enableSpeaker()
        print("ok")
    }
}
```

I could see that the ToneOutputUnit code was being called and was stepping through the various functions but no sound was produced. I also tried calling 'enableSpeaker' before 'startToneForDuration' but also no sound. What am I missing?

Comment: Here's a tone generator class I converted to Swift 2.x and the new iOS Audio Unit v3 API: https://gist.github.com/hotpaw2/630a466cc830e3d129b9

Comment: Many thanks. I tried calling this from the following viewcontroller and no sound was produced. Can you help further by saying how it should be called? At this point I don't really care what tone is produced. I just want to hear something that I can vary. [I now see that I can't insert code into a comment. I'll try adding to the original.]

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: Robert, move the "unit" variable to be an instance variable instead of a local one. Right now it's being popped off the stack when viewDidLoad returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course Gene De Lisa is right. The "unit" variable needs to be declared outside of viewDidLoad so it doesn't get deallocated right away. Also, "unit.enableSpeaker()" needs to be before "unit.startToneForDuration(0.5)". However even with those 2 changes I got no sound. After more head scratching I found two scaling errors in hotpaw2's ToneOutputUnit.swift (in github).

1) In the function startToneForDuration the line "toneCount = Int32(round( time / sampleRate ))" should be "toneCount = Int32(time * sampleRate)".

2) And in the function setToneVolume the line "v0 = vol / 32768.0" should be "v0 = vol * 32768.0".

With those two changes it works and produces a tone with volume and duration that seem reasonable.

@Hotpaw2: I hope you will update your version in github. It's a nicely written class that will help others.