# how to pan sound in swift

Tags: ios, swift, audio

I have try this code implement from. https://gist.github.com/hotpaw2/630a466cc830e3d129b9

```
let toneOutputUnit = ToneOutputUnit()

    toneOutputUnit.enableSpeaker()
    toneOutputUnit.setToneTime(t: 1)
    toneOutputUnit.setFrequency(freq: 1000)
    toneOutputUnit.setToneVolume(vol: 0.5)

    toneOutputUnit.startToneForDuration(time: 1)
```

but no function to pan left or right (I want to pan only left 100% and right 100%)

which class is pan command in?

Comment: you need implementation of AVAudioMixerNode with AVAudioEngine

Comment: You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38909493/matt-gallaghers-ios-tone-generator/38938351#38938351), Matt Gallagher's iOS Tone Generator.